# Reduce spacing between words in itemize that's inside of a tabular enviroment

Tags: tables, spacing, itemize

I have a problem where the following itemize inside of my table has a lot of extra space between the words?
Inserting a new item doesn't have the same problem however.
[image: Image showing the formatting problem]

```
\section{Læringsmål}
\begin{center}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{
    | >{\columncolor[gray]{.8}\centering\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
    | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \caption{Kravliste} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
    \textbf{Læringsmål} & 
    \textbf{Hvordan vil jeg opfylde læringsmålene}? & 
    \textbf{Opfyldelses grad} \\
    \endfirsthead

    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
    \textbf{Læringsmål} &
    \textbf{Hvordan vil jeg opfylde læringsmålene?} &
    \textbf{Opfyldelses grad} \\
    \endhead

    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{\small Forsætter på næste side\ldots}
    \endfoot

    \endlastfoot

    \hline 
    \textbf{Udvikle webapps specielt i forhold til i Flutter} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
        \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
        \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
        \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{itemize}
    & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Bygge et større system op og integrerer eksisterende systemer ind i projektet.} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
        \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
        \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
        \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{itemize}
    &\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Anvende agile metoder} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
        \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
        \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
        \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{itemize}
    &\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Bedre til at arbejde selvstændigt} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
        \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
        \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
        \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{itemize}
    &\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Udarbejdelse af struktur og planlægning} &
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
        \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
        \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
        \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{itemize}
    &\\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{center}
```

I would like to know why the last item is fine but not the others?

Comment: Additionally I would suggest to use [package `enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to reduce the left margin (aka indent) of the items.

Comment: Thank you James. I tried the answer in the thread and it worked.
To you as well cabohah cause I was wandering why I couldn't get the options to work with enumerated enviroments

Comment: Dear all, I've reopened the question as it's NOT a dupe of the earlier posting.

Comment: The last line isn't stretched because it's only one line, and doesn't have to be processed as a paragraph.  As for the others, they should be set `\raggedright` to get rid of the uneven spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you employ the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and its macros `\newlist` and `\setlist` to create a bespoke itemize-like environment -- called `tabitemize` in the code below -- that typesets its contents very compactly. The lines in the itemized list should also not be fully justified. E.g.,

```
% create a new itemize-type list environment
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1} 
% set the properties of the new list environment
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,left=0pt,nosep,
   before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight},
   after ={\end{minipage}} 
   }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{xltabular,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for "\RaggedRight" macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

% new code:

\usepackage{enumitem}
% create a new itemize-type list environment
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1} 
% set the properties of the new list environment
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,left=0pt,nosep,
   before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\RaggedRight},
   after ={\end{minipage}} 
   }

% optional:
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Læringsmål}

\begingroup % localize scope of next two instructions
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{%
    | >{\bfseries\columncolor[gray]{.8}}L | L | L |}
    
    %% headers and footers
    
    \caption{Kravliste} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
    Læringsmål & 
    \textbf{Hvordan vil jeg opfylde læringsmålene}? & 
    \textbf{Opfyldelses grad} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\tablename\ \thetable, fortsat} \\[1ex]
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
    Læringsmål &
    \textbf{Hvordan vil jeg opfylde læringsmålene?} &
    \textbf{Opfyldelses grad} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\small Forsætter på næste side\ldots}\\
    \endfoot
    
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
     
     
    %% body of table
    
    Udvikle webapps specielt i forhold til i Flutter &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
    \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
    \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
    \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{tabitemize} & 
    \\
    \hline
    
    Bygge et større system op og integrerer eksisterende systemer ind i projektet. &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
    \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
    \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
    \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{tabitemize} & 
    \\
    
    \hline
    Anvende agile metoder &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
    \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
    \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
    \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{tabitemize} & 
    \\
    
    \hline
    Bedre til at arbejde selvstændigt &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
    \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
    \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
    \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{tabitemize} & 
    \\
    
    \hline   
    Udarbejdelse af struktur og planlægning &
    \begin{tabitemize}
    \item Hvilke arbejdsopgaver har jeg løst som understøtter læringsmål?
    \item Hvilke udfordringer har jeg mødt undervejs?
    \item Hvad har jeg gjort for at løse udfordringerne?
    \item Har målet været hensigtsmæssigt og hvad har jeg lært af det?
    \end{tabitemize} & 
    \\

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```